# Facing some xmlns:app errors while Generating Signed Build apk

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am facing some xmlns:app errors while Generating Signed Build apk file on Android Studio. Issues are on xmlns:app part. Tried all the possible fix available here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">




</LinearLayout>
```

**I am getting Error Messages Like :**

```
D:\Andro\App\woo\app\src\main\res\layout\layout_categories_6.xml:4: Error: Suspicious namespace and prefix combination [NamespaceTypo]
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
D:\Andro\App\woo\app\src\main\res\layout-ldrtl\layout_product_grid_lg.xml:5: Error: Suspicious namespace and prefix combination [NamespaceTypo]
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
D:\Andro\App\woo\app\src\main\res\layout\layout_product_grid_lg.xml:5: Error: Suspicious namespace and prefix combination [NamespaceTypo]
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
D:\Andro\App\woo\app\src\main\res\layout-ldrtl\layout_product_grid_sm.xml:5: Error: Suspicious namespace and prefix combination [NamespaceTypo]
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
D:\Andro\App\woo\app\src\main\res\layout\layout_product_grid_sm.xml:5: Error: Suspicious namespace and prefix combination [NamespaceTypo]
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
D:\Andro\App\woo\app\src\main\res\layout-ldrtl\layout_product_list_lg.xml:5: Error: Suspicious namespace and prefix combination [NamespaceTypo]
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
D:\Andro\App\woo\app\src\main\res\layout\layout_product_list_lg.xml:5: Error: Suspicious namespace and prefix combination [NamespaceTypo]
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

   Explanation for issues of type "NamespaceTypo":
   Accidental misspellings in namespace declarations can lead to some very
   obscure error messages. This check looks for potential misspellings to help
   track these down.

7 errors, 0 warnings
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, there are two scenarios where you must've messed this up, so read very carefully.

1. You're using `app` namespace declaration for `tools`, you've used

   ```
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   ```

   instead of

   ```
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   ```

**OR**

2. Maybe you wanted to use `app` namespace, but instead used the path for `tools`.

   So you used:

   ```
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   ```

   instead of

   ```
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   ```

which you should correct.

Now, if you added one layout which contains this error, I'd have been able to help you with where you made the mistake, but, correct declarations are:

> ```
> xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
> ```

and

> ```
> xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
> ```

don't mismatch them, and you won't get the error. And, to fix your error instantly, add both the **correct declarations** (i.e. the **bottom two highlighted in yellow**) wherever you're getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">
```

Comment: @Andy what is the name of your xml file ?